# Visual Studio 2019 connecting to Access Database - Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

Trying to connect an Access Database to a WPF project in Visual Studio 2019. My version of MS Access is 2016.

When trying to connect the dataset, I get the error in the title. 
Research shows a lot of solutions to install runtimes, none of which worked. None of them are even able to be installed. Trying to install the Access 2016 x64 runtime, gave me the error (paraphrasing) "Can not install 64-bit runtime due to conflicting 32 bit Microsoft Office components". So I uninstalled the 32-bit components and the installer then failed with a whole bunch of errors.

If I try to install the x86 runtime, it gives me the error "Can not install 32-bit runtime due to conflicting 64 bit Microsoft Office components".

I spent a good few hours on it, and I'm stumped as to why this is not included functionality.
Have tried targeting the project to 32 bit, 64 bit and any CPU.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Could you try to compile your project as anyCPU, it might  work

Comment: You can and need to install the 32bit version. To do so you need a little trick. I forgot which but you'll find it! I needed it last week, but my memory is no longer what it never was.. Maybe press shift or such??? Both version can coexist.

Comment: Ah, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76/why-cant-32-and-64-bit-access-database-engine-aceoledb-dataproviders-coexist?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) it is : _Not really documented, but I did find a way to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Just add the command line argument "/passive" to the command:

"C:\directory path\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" /passive_

Comment: Note that the post has many convoluted answers. Do try my comment on the question first!

Comment: The /passive thing doesn't work. I tried! I was able to install the runtime but only if I uninstalled office (and therefore Access itself...). It staggers me that this is not plug and play. Why have a great, easy to use database designer and a great, easy to use development IDE and not have them be compatible out of the box?

What are other good solutions for bundling a database with an app. I'm proficient in most forms of SQL but most experience in web dev with MySQL or PgSQL. All I want to do is have an app that loads a database!